# How to pass PK to dispatch_detail

Tags: django, tastypie

Here's the url I have for Resource's list:

```
url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/stats%s$' % (
                self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name='api_dispatch_regions_stats')
```

I need to do the same thing for the detail, something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>)/stats%s$' % (
                    self._meta.resource_name, self._meta.pk trailing_slash()),
                    self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name='api_dispatch_regions_stats')
```

so I would be able to do something like:

```
def alter_detail_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    if 'stats' in request.path:
        do_something()
    return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would do

```
url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\d+)/stats%s$' % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
    self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'),
    name='api_dispatch_regions_stats')
```

and Django cares for the rest but I am not sure what you really want to do.